# Independent Random Variables with Standard Normal Distribution

Tags: probability

I have this question... X and Z are independent random variables having both a standard normal distribution. Now, Y = X^2 + Z. How can I show that E(Y|X) = X^2? I tried solving it but I ended up with 1.

E(Y|X) = E[Y] assuming that both Y and X are independent
       = E[X^2+Z]
       = E[X^2] + E[Z]
       = Var[X] + (E[X])^2 + E[Z]
       = 1 + 0 + 0
       = 1

Comment: The question doesn't say X and Y are independent, it says X and Z are.

Comment: $E(Z|X) = E(Z) = 0$ (independence) and $E(X^2 | X) = X^2.$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question doesn't say X and Y are independent, it says X and Z are.

Since $Y=X^2+Z$, then $$\begin{align}\Bbb E[Y\mid X] &= \Bbb E[X^2 + Z\mid X] \\ &= \Bbb E[X^2\mid X] + \Bbb E[Z\mid X] \\ & = X^2 + \Bbb E[Z] &&\text{independence} \\ & = X^2\end{align}$$

In particular, note that $E[X^2\mid X]$ is a random variable that behaves as $X^2$.

Comment: ok...that is why I got it wrong...How come E[X^2|X] became X^2? It should be E[X^2].

Comment: @ZanderAssand $X^2$ is not independent of $X$, it is determined by it.  That is: What do you expect $X^2$ to be when you know what $X$ is?

Comment: @ZanderAssand Moreover, $X^2$ is X-measurable. (What is the definition of conditional expectation?)

Comment: Im sorry, I don't get it...what I know is that E[X|Y] = E[X] if X and Y are independent. From it, it follows that E[X^2|X] will just be E[X^2], why eliminate E?

Comment: $X^2$ is not independent of $X$. On the contrary, knowing $X$ completely determines $X^2$, so they are in some sense the opposite of being independent. Conditional expectation does not produce a number, it produces a random variable. It is your best guess of $X^2$ if you know the value of $X$, which is clearly just $X^2$ itself.

Comment: @ZanderAssand To get some intuition, consider conditioning on the event that $X=k$, which is $\mathsf E(X^2\mid X{=}k) = k^2$.

Comment: Or to put it another way - if you know the value of $X$, you know the value of $X^2$ - they are *dependent*. On the other hand, if you know the result of coin flip $X$, you *don't* know the value of die roll $Z$ - they are *independent*.

Comment: @GrahamKemp By intuition, sounds correct. Can you prove this mathematically?

Comment: Clearly $\mathsf E(X^2\mid X=k) = k^2\, \mathsf P(X=k\mid X=k)$